# How to use "useI18n" on "server/api" directory

Tags: typescript, internationalization, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

I'm using `@nuxtjs/i18n` version `^8.0.0-beta.7` and here is my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import en from "./locales/en.json";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: { strict: true, shim: false },
  components: true,
  runtimeConfig: {
    //...
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    //...
  ],
  vueuse: { ssrHandlers: true },
  i18n: {
    vueI18n: {
      legacy: false,
      locale: "en",
      availableLocales: ["en", "fr"],
      messages: { en },
    },
  },
});
```

`locales/en.json`

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

All components inside `pages` and `components` are working fine, however when I do the same thing with `server/api` directory the error occurs:

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] useI18n is not defined                                                                         21:49:12  
  at /D:/Projects/saucemoe/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:547:17
  at /D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:668:47
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async Object.handler (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:723:19)
  at async Server.toNodeHandle (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:798:7)
```

`server/api/test.get.ts`

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const { t } = useI18n();
  const foo = t("foo");

  return { foo };
});
```

But if I add `import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";` I get another error:

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Must be called at the top of a setup function                                                  21:59:08
  at createCompileError (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/@intlify/message-compiler/dist/message-compiler.mjs:54:19)
  at createI18nError (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.mjs:92:12)
  at useI18n (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.mjs:2229:15)
  at /D:/Projects/saucemoe/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:548:17
  at /D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:668:47
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async Object.handler (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:723:19)
  at async Server.toNodeHandle (/D:/Projects/saucemoe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:798:7)
```

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const { t } = useI18n();
  const foo = t("foo");

  return { foo };
});
```

So in summary, how can I use `useI18n` in `server/api` directory, many thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you sovled this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`useI18n` can only be used in the Vue Setup context and is therefore not available in Nitro.  One way to use vue-i18n in Nuxt's API handlers (`/server/api`) is to add a file in `/server/utils` which recreates a I18n instance in Nitro that is automatically imported in `/server/api/`.

In your case, this would be `/server/utils/i18n.ts`

```js
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import type { I18nOptions } from "vue-i18n";

import en from "../../locales/en.json";

const messages: I18nOptions["messages"] = Object.assign({
  en: en,
});

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: "en",
  availableLocales: ["en", "fr"], // note: you declare two available locales but only have one in messages
  messages,
});

export const { t, locale } = i18n.global;
```

and your api event handler would be modified this way:

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const foo = t("foo"); // t is auto-imported

  return { foo };
});
```

You can modify the locale by assigning it to the `locale` ref (`locale.value = "fr"`). And you need to pass it to the event request.

This might not be the most performant way to proceed as I'm not fully acquainted with the way Nitro/Nuxt is structured, but it works.